# Issue with asp.net report viewer binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting, reportviewer

I have a problem with asp.net report viewer I have to display two SQL table data

I made a function for this that is working fine with html reporting but I wants to display this in report viewer in my website.
the following code is working fine with Gridview but not binding with report viewer.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        reports();
    }

}
private void reports()
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable da = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();

    db.CommandTimeout = 200;
    var ans = (from data in db.tblAttributeDatas
               where data.nMainDataId == 3291
               select data).ToList();


    List<tblSectionAttribute> cols = (from Attrib in db.tblSectionAttributes
                                      from main in db.tblAttributeDatas
                                      where Attrib.nId == main.nSectionAttributeId
                                      &&
                                      main.nMainDataId == 3291
                                      select Attrib).ToList();
    int a = 1;
    foreach (var item in cols)
    {


        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn(a.ToString() + "." + item.strAttributeName);
        dc1.DefaultValue = "";
        da.Columns.Add(dc1);
        a++;



    }
    int row = 0;
    DataRow dr = da.NewRow();
    foreach (var item1 in ans)
    {

        DataColumn d = new DataColumn();
        if (item1.strValue != "")
        {
            d = new DataColumn(row.ToString() + "." + item1.strValue);
        }
        else
        {
            d = new DataColumn("not Answered");
        }
        dr[row] = d;
        //da.Rows.Add(dr);
        //   dr = da.Rows[row];

        row++;
    }
    da.Rows.Add(dr);
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");

    ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet",da);
    ReportViewer1.DataBind();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);



}
```

and my aspx code is

```
     <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc">
       <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource  />     
       </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

and output is blank only blank ReportViewer display in browser with Report Viewer built-in heading and paging no error just black output of Report Viewer
please help

Comment: Include information on what happens with the current code. Is it producing an error? Is nothing displayed?

Comment: hi i am not getting any error i Just geting  blank report Viewer output in browser but if i bind this to GridView i get my desire output i think it is just binding issue with report viewer

Answer (score 0):

- first of all you configure your dataset.xsd file with  your rdlc file
- then after create datatable in dataset
- and design your report and simply drag and drop your datatable field in rdlc file

  i  hope  it's information help you

  http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-create-RDLC-report-step-by-step-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx